# How to add indentation inside tkinter text box?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, indentation

-EDIT I used the word indentation incorrectly in this question. I meant to to refer to the starting of new lines.

---

I'm creating a python weather app with the tkinter UI library, It works but using the  [Open weather map API](https://openweathermap.org/). The user will input a city name (CITY var) and using a predefined link body the program plugs in the city name (CITY var) and requests the city's weather data from the open weather map site using that link. The whole process of requesting the data is handled by this function

```
 def getData(CITY):
    BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    API_KEY = "MY-API-KEY"

    #our url to send to
    URL = BASE_URL + "q=" + CITY + "&appid=" + API_KEY

    # HTTP request
    response = requests.get(URL)

    # checking the status code of the request
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # getting data in the json format
        data = response.json()
        # getting the main dict block
        main = data['main']
        # getting temperature
        temperature = main['temp']
        # getting the humidity
        humidity = main['humidity']
        # getting the pressure
        pressure = main['pressure']
        # weather report
        report = data['weather']
        # print info
        print(f"{CITY:-^30}")
        print(f"Temperature: {temperature}")
        print(f"Humidity: {humidity}")
        print(f"Pressure: {pressure}")
        print(f"Weather Report: {report[0]['description']}")



    else:
        # showing the error message
        print("Error in the HTTP request")
```

When run with the city name new York the terminal outputs something like this.
[image: output in terminal]
Its clean and has good indents. But now I need to put this info into the apps text box's. I do this using this code.

```
City.set(CITY)

#add the citys name to a list of all citys 
History.tag_configure("right", justify='right')
History.insert("1.0", f"{CITY:-^30}")
History.tag_add("right", "1.0", "end")

#adds info to main textbox
InfoBox.tag_configure("right", justify='right')
InfoBox.delete('1.0', END)
InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"{CITY:-^30}"))
InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"Temperature: {temperature}"))
InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"Humidity: {humidity}"))
InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"Pressure: {pressure}"))
InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"Weather Report: {report[0]['description']}"))
InfoBox.tag_add("right", "1.0", "end")

#add city info to our info box with all previous citys info
CityUpdate.tag_configure("right", justify='right')
CityUpdate.insert("1.0", (f"{CITY:-^30}"))
CityUpdate.insert("1.0", (f"Temperature: {temperature}"))
CityUpdate.insert("1.0", (f"Humidity: {humidity}"))
CityUpdate.insert("1.0", (f"Pressure: {pressure}"))
CityUpdate.insert("1.0", (f"Weather Report: {report[0]['description']}"))
CityUpdate.tag_add("right", "1.0", "end")
```

The issue comes up here when the code shows something like this in the text boxes.
[image: output in app]
Its the correct information but the indentation is gone. My question is how can I get that indentation back so it looks as good as it was in the terminal?

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with indentation so much as a problem with newlines. Be sure to add `\n` at the end of each of the lines you insert. For example, `InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"Temperature: {temperature}\n"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem with the indentation. What I see is that you're failing to add a newline when inserting a line of text. You also keep inserting at the start instead of appending at the end which is unusual; I don't know whether or not that is intentional.

To add a newline, your insert statement should look something like this:

```
InfoBox.insert("1.0", (f"{CITY:-^30}\n"))
```

As to the question in the title, the text widget supports tabs via the `tabs` configuration option. By default tab stops are every 8 average-sized characters but you have complete control over the placement of tabstops, as well as how text is aligned to those tab stops (eg: left, center, right, or numeric).

Comment: Looking at the order of the text in the terminal, compared with the order that the OP inserts the text, they did intend to insert at the beginning. But they don't seem to know about `insert("end", ...`, which would save them from having to insert the text in backwards order.